# how to send and receieve data from offline database to a web service?

Tags: c#, android, xml, winforms, web-services

i am working on an android application. I am using xml services to get and retrieve data from my online sql server database.
I have another database which is offline. i want to check a value which will be filled from android device. the value will be checked from offline database. i made a windows form application which is connected with my offline database. Now i want to know that by which method i can send data to windows form application from web service and get reply as well as also.
My service is in XML format..
Can anybody help me in this problem??
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: to connect to your window form app it woul required to be local to the server hosting the service. The thing is that if you have a winform app local and an offline database that mean the service himself ca also access it. Therefore no need to access the win form app to access the offline database. the webservice can as well directly

Comment: do u mean web service can access my offline database also?? My webservice is Online

Comment: a web service can even start notepad on the server if you like with the proper process start.

Comment: I am sorry i am new bee in web services. i just want to know how can i access my local database server with a web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to put as answer so it doesn't become a chat.

Yes, most of time the account that IIS run on is high enough to access any files on the computer or at least a dll you might have made that connect to your database.

You can easily connect to file `c:\MyOfflineData\db.mdb` (lets say access for sake of example)
all you need is the proper ADO connection string. It works as well as any other connection.

Also BTW you do NOT need to have your SQL server open to the internet. For example all my setup have always been like this :

1 server with IIS and all my Web service opened to the internet

1 server with SQL that is only internal and have no internet access.

my services can connect to the SQL since it's on the network and can do whatever i want but no one from outside can see my SQL server. so technically my whole SQL server is "Offline" as you call.

Comment: try using ODBC connection. Or verify your are using a FULL path and not a relative path. Because Web services actually run in a temp folder hidden somewhere very deep.